# SocketTimeOutException in Android Socket Client

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have developed a chat application in Java (both server and client).
I am creating an Android client for the same.
I copied all code from the Java client, everything is working fine (like socket creation, Handshake, etc.), and I can send messages.

But when it comes to read messages, it does not block read operation.
And it throws an exception.

Here is a log.

> 04-26 18:00:33.552: W/System.err(6775): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
>   04-26 18:00:33.562: W/System.err(6775):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:492)
>   04-26 18:00:33.562: W/System.err(6775):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
>   04-26 18:00:33.572: W/System.err(6775):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)

My read command is

```
for (int i = 0; i < n2; i += this.socket.getInputStream().read(b, n + i, n2 - i)) {

}
```

What should I change when converting this Desktop Java client to an Android app?

Comment: Why do you call `read` as part of the for `expression` and do nothing in the `for` body?

Comment: This expression is working fine with java client application.

Comment: Sure it is, but what's the point of it? You do nothing with the `char` that was read.

Comment: Try checking the value of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time. Maybe it is really short on Android devices.